# Подскажите как реализовать такой текст c css?

Tags: css, css3, текст

Всем привет!
Никак не выходит реализовать данную вещь.
Перепробовал все, что знал.
Как можно начальные буквы Л Л.
Именно с помощью текста

[image]

```css
body {
  background: rgb(0,0,0);
}
.text_container {
    position: relative;
}
.main_text {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.text {
    z-index: 2;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    color: #f8ff13;
}
.text_border {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 28px;
    top: 0;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_container">
  <span class="text main_text">Лайки</span>
  <span class="text text_border">Лайки</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Прямо так, как на картинке, не очень легко.

Comment: Можно по другому

Comment: Обрезать полбуквы - это надо очень постараться, почти никак. А остальное через text-shadow.

Comment: А может, вам не нужен текст? Отрисовать картинку в любом векторном редакторе будет проще и качественнее

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEpMRzo вариант ?

Comment: Я просто думаю, а если текст поменять.. svg не вариант наверно .

Comment: попробуйте поменяйте но по другому будет гемморой жёсткий, можно разбить первые два символа на span и ограничить ширину с overflow, я делал из ходя из того текста который в примере

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vYXzrmL вот так например можно на css

Comment: Спасибо большое. Попробую с этим способом, если не пойдёт, воспользуюсь svg,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если такое будет использовать пару раз на странице и будет очень редко редактироваться - используйте картинку.
Для индексации можете использовать трюк, который использует у себя **Instagram**:

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 0;
}

h1 > img {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <img src="//i.imgur.com/R7WZfH4.png">
  Лайки
</h1>
```

Если же это будет редактироваться, то смотрите в сторону **SVG**

Answer (score 3):

Тень можно сделать так:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

div {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 16px;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 yellow, 1px 1px yellow, -1px 1px 0 yellow, 1px -1px yellow, 
               -8px 0 0 black,
               -9px 1px 0 white, -9px -1px 0 white, -7px 1px 0 white, -7px -1px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<div>Лайки</div>
```

Comment: К сожалению, автор в комментах уже уточнил, что его интересует не тень (а обновлять текст вопроса как обычно никто не хочет...)

Comment: @andreymal, а я уже тень сделал - не удалять же её теперь.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background-color: #292a25;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.text_container {
  position: relative;
}

span {
  color: #f8ff13;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 0 currentColor, 0 -1px 0 currentColor, 1px 0 0 currentColor, 0 1px 0 currentColor;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  color: #20201e;
  z-index: -1;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 0 white, 0 -1px 0 white, 1px 0 0 white, 0 1px 0 white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="text_container">
    <span class="text">ЛАЙКИ</span>
    <span class="text">//ЛАЙКИ</span>
</div>
```

Comment: С этой частью проблем нет, а начало как реализовать не пойму

Comment: @ErnestKH почему вы не конкретизировали свой вопрос, что вам нужно создать только первые два символа, а не весь остальной текст.

Comment: @ErnestKH svg поможет

Comment: @ErnestKH я не знаю что у вас за символы перед текстом, я обновил ответ

Comment: первые буквы это тот же текст ЛАЙКИ, который видимо скрывается.